# Is there a way to view list of tables and columns in hue

Tags: impala, hue

I'm trying to get a list of tables and their columns using Hive/Impala.  I know I can use Show Tables to get a table list but is there a way i can also view their columns as well in the same result set?

Comment: The metastore manager should show all this info by default as you look at tables.  http://gethue.com/browsing-hive-tables-data-and-metadata-is-getting-faster-and-prettier/

Comment: thanks I will check this out